# Problem with mysqldump: "--defaults-extra-file" option is not working as expected

Tags: mysql, database, windows

I run the following command from the Windows command line to backup my database:

```
...\right_path\mysqldump --add-drop-database --databases my_database_name
                         --defaults-extra-file=d:\1.cnf
```

where `d:\1.cnf` contains the following:

```
[client]
user="my_user"
password="my_password"
```

Unfortunately, I got the following error message:

```
mysqldump: unknown variable 'defaults-extra-file=d:\1.cnf'
```

If I do:

```
...\right_path\mysqldump --add-drop-database --databases my_database_name
                         --user="my_user" --password="my_password"
```

it works as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

I found the answer: `--defaults-extra-file` must be the first option. This works as expected:

```
...\right_path\mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=d:\1.cnf
                         --add-drop-database --databases my_database_name
```

Comment: In addition: the sequence is also critical when you pass normal "--defaults-file" parameter to e.g. mysqld

Comment: On some systems, mysql and mysqldump are set up as aliases such as `alias mysql='mysql --skip-secure-auth'`. So if you set --defaults-extra-file first and it still does not work, check that no such alias is in place, using eg. `which mysql`.

Answer (score 3):

For future reference:

The accepted answer is correct and it is required to place `--defaults-extra-file` option at the **first** position.

```bash
mysql --defaults-extra-file=/path/.mydbcreds.cnf --host db --user root
```

If you want to try how this approach work with Docker containers, you can follow these steps:

```bash
echo "[client]\npassword=example\n">.mydbcreds.cnf
docker network create dbnet
docker run --network dbnet -it --rm \
    --name db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=example \
    mysql
docker run --network dbnet -it --rm \
    --name db-client -v "$PWD:/app/" mysql \
    mysql --defaults-extra-file=/app/.mydbcreds.cnf \
        --host db --user root \
        -e "SHOW SCHEMAS;"
```

Not to forget to keep credentials safe and out of VCS:

```bash
echo ".mydbcreds.cnf">>.gitignore
```

The file can contain all connection parameters (host, user, etc.).

Unfortunately, this file **can not** contain **database name**, which would be awesome to have a different file per environment.
Now we have all for connection in file and DB name set in the command.

Comment: This doesn't answer the person's questions.

Comment: The accepted answer is correct. As noted, this is for future reference if somebody is also searching for the same keywords from the question, as I did. This is an Docker example where to store credentials correctly and how to read it with --defaults-extra-file. This stuff is so rare and opening a new question just for a small note is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Also meet this problem. Found there's another situation that would cause `--defaults-extra-file` option not recognized.

When you changed IFS in script, it's possible to hit this problem. The solution is to reset IFS before execute mysql statement.

For reference.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is Linux-specific, but my searches brought me here.

I'm using bitnami's LAMP stack, and found out that their "mysqldump" is actually a script:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/lampstack-5.5.3-0/mysql/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
case "$@" in
  *--no-defaults*)
    exec $0.bin "$@"
    exit
esac
exec $0.bin --defaults-file=/opt/lampstack-5.5.3-0/mysql/my.cnf "$@"
```

which doesn't appear to allow `--defaults-file` to be passed in... and work (as per the accepted answer here).

Comment: @LeifSegen just call the .bin version directly.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility for --defaults-extra-file to be ignored can by a .my.cnf file in your home directory.
The ~/.my.cnf file overrules the values you are trying to set in --defaults-extra-file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be that you invoked MySQL this way:

```bash
mysql --defaults-extra-file my.cnf ...
```

Note that at least on MySQL 5.7 the program doesn't support separating command-line options and their arguments with space characters, equal sign character must be used in order for the program to recognize the option:

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file=my.cnf ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same errors as shown below:

> [ERROR] unknown variable 'defaults-file=C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini'.

> [ERROR] unknown variable 'defaults-extra-file=C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini'.

When I tried to log in with `-u john` and `--defaults-file=` or `--defaults-extra-file=` respectively as shown below:

```
mysql -u john --defaults-file='C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini'
```

Or:

```
mysql -u john --defaults-extra-file='C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini'
```

So, I changed the order of `-u john` and `--defaults-file=` or `--defaults-extra-file=` respectively as shown below, then I could log in:

```
mysql --defaults-file='C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini' -u john
```

Or:

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file='C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini' -u john
```