# How to select a MySQL database through CLI?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-cli, mysqlcommand, mysql-command-line-client

I've managed to get into MySQL using the command line terminal, but when I tried to enter some SQL, it said 'no database selected'

how do I select a database? my database name is:  photogallery

What code do I use to select it?

Answer (score 178):

Use `USE`. This will enable you to select the database.

```
USE photogallery;
```

> [12.8.4: USE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/use.html)

You can also specify the database you want when connecting:

```
$ mysql -u user -p photogallery
```

Comment: Not the latest thread but I thought I might leave my 2 cents here. The command line provided is not quite correct. To specify password in command line, you set --password=<pass_goes_here> to use database via command line, you put in mysql -u <user> -p <database_name> this way the -p means that mysql client will prompt for password input and not read it from command line

Answer (score 39):

While invoking the `mysql` CLI, you can specify the database name through the `-D` option.  From `mysql --help`:

```
-D, --database=name Database to use.
```

I use this command:

```
mysql -h <db_host> -u <user> -D <db_name> -p
```

Comment: OP should mark this answer as the correct one.

Comment: THIS. This is the answer for the CLI.

Answer (score 24):

Switch to a database.

```
mysql> use [db name];
```

[MySQL Commands](http://www.pantz.org/software/mysql/mysqlcommands.html)

Answer (score 15):

Hope this helps.

```
use [YOUR_DB_NAME];
```

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively, you can give the "full location" to the database in your queries a la:

```
SELECT photo_id FROM [my database name].photogallery;
```

If using one more often than others, use `USE`.  Even if you do, you can still use the `database.table` syntax.

Answer (score 9):

Use the following steps to select the database:

```
mysql -u username -p
```

it will prompt for password, Please enter password.
Now list all the databases

```
show databases;
```

select the database which you want to select using the command:

```
use databaseName;
```

select data from any table:

```
select * from tableName limit 10;
```

You can select your database using the command `use photogallery;`
Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

```
USE database_name;
```

eg. if your database's name is `gregs_list`, then it will be like this >>

```
USE gregs_list;
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can select `apple` database with login as shown below:

```
mysql -u john -p apple
```

Or:

```
mysql -u john -p apple
```

Or:

```
mysql -u john -p -D apple
```

Or:

```
mysql -u john -p --database=apple
```

Or:

```
mysql -u john -p --database apple
```

And, you can select `apple` database after login as shown below:

```
mysql> use apple
```

Or:

```
mysql> USE apple
```

Or:

```
mysql> \u apple
```

Or:

```
mysql> connect apple
```

Or:

```
mysql> CONNECT apple
```

Or:

```
mysql> \r apple
```

Be careful, you cannot select `apple` database with `\U` because there is the error as shown below:

```
mysql> \U apple
```

> ERROR: Unknown command '\U'.

And, you cannot select `apple` database with `\R` because `\R`(`prompt`) is used to change MySQL prompt as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690553/can-i-change-the-mysql-prompt-with-selected-database-as-we-do-in-hive/77471378#77471378) exlains how to change the default prompt `mysql>` :

```
mysql> \R apple
PROMPT set to 'apple'
apple
```

Or on Windows, you can set the database under `[mysql]` in `my.ini` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453555/mysql-configuration-file-sections/77456323#77456323) explains `[mysql]` and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597884/where-is-mysqls-my-ini-located-on-windows/77461989#77461989) explains where `my.ini` is located on Windows:

```ini
# "my.ini"

[mysql]
...
database='apple'
```

Then, you can select `apple` database with login by setting `my.ini`'s location to `--defaults-file=` or `--defaults-extra-file=` as shown below. *`--defaults-file=` or `--defaults-extra-file=` must be the 1st option otherwise there is [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836214/problem-with-mysqldump-defaults-extra-file-option-is-not-working-as-expecte/77463030#77463030):

```
mysql --defaults-file='C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini' -u john -p
```

Or:

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file='C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini' -u john -p
```