# How to remotely connect to MySQL on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, windows-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I have installed MySQL on a Windows Server 2012 R2 using Microsoft's Web Platform installer.

What I'm having a problem with is how to remotely connect to it? I'm able to launch the MySQL command prompt on the server and can see that it is running on port 3306, uses root as the username, the correct password and I can see the hostname (the name of the server).

I have enabled an inbound rule in Windows Firewall for port 3306 but is there anything else I need to do? I'm trying to connect using MySQL Workbench on my PC but not getting very far.

Thanks,
Steven.

Comment: What did you try to connect? The server seems to be prepared properly, so maybe it's the client machine that has a problem (firewall outbound rule, wrong IP address etc).

Comment: @MikeLischke: default server configuration binds to 127.0.0.1 disallowing remote connections.

Comment: ... disallowing remote connections. And you want to connect remotely?

Comment: Hi there, yes I'm looking to connect remotely through MySQL Workbench on my PC. Would I need to specify the bind address in my.ini?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem, exactly as your description

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you need to correct your `my.ini` and either comment the `bind-address` variable, which is set to `127.0.0.1` by default, or set it to your server's IP address value.

For locations, please refer to: [MySQL my.ini location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597884/mysql-my-ini-location)

Comment: I can't seem to find the my.cnf file on the server? I've checked in C:\Windows\my.cnf and C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.cnf

Comment: My bad, on windows it's my.ini and it's not there by default. Edited my answer to refer you to the right locations.