# Change isolation level in MySQL (Windows)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to change the isolation level om MySQL. It was installed on Windows using the installer http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

I am following the directions here [MySQL my.ini location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597884/mysql-my-ini-location)

I added this line to my.ini:

```
transaction_isolation=READ-COMMITTED
```

I found the file in C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7

I stopped and started the MySQL57 service.

I ran this query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tx_isolation';
```

It returns REPEATABLE-READ

It seems that the change didn't take. How do I change it?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with MySQL workbench. The query correctly shows "READ-COMMITTED" when I run it while logged into mysql from the cmd prompt.

Looking at MySQL Workbench's settings it has the configuration file as located in C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server **5.5**, which doesn't exist.