# rmysql - Error: Can't initialize character set unknown

Tags: mysql, r

Trying to connect to MySQL from r:

```
library(RMySQL)
mydb<-dbConnect(MySQL(), user='root', password='123', dbname='mydb', host='localhost')
```

Getting the following error:

```
Error in .local(drv, ...) : Failed to connect to database: 
Error: Can't initialize character set unknown (path: compiled_in)
```

Using

```
R ver is 3.3.3
MySQL is '8.0.12'
default_character_set_name in MySQL is utf8mb4
```

Comment: HAve you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50053961/error-r-cannot-connect-to-mysql

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when I installed MySQL 8.0.19
Solution is locate and open your my.cnf and set character-set for mysql server.

```
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```