# Why am I getting a MySQL error in cmd when trying to change my password?

Tags: mysql, cmd

I am trying to change my MySQL password. However, when I go into cmd and type the directory of my my.ini file, it tells me.

> mysqld: [ERROR] Could not open required defaults file: Windows-SSD(C:)\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini
>
> mysqld: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!

Please help, I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyc5b3yT2tI) tutorial. I am sure that the directory is correct (I copied it).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your MySQL installation is missing my.ini file. Check if it's there.

It was a problem in 5.5 version (I'm not sure about 5.7), but you can try the solution from this [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14598246/12257250).