# How to set mysql 8 innodb_buffer_pool_size?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to deal with the dreaded "The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size" error. Many entries in Stack Overflow suggest increasing innodb_buffer_pool_size from its default 8 MB.

I verify the current buffer pool size with `SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size;` and get the default 8388608. I get the same result in the output of `mysqld --help --verbose`

Following other stack overflow entries and the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html) I create a file c:\my.cnf that contains

```
[mysqld]
innodb_buffer_pool_size=67108864
```

and then I restart the Windows service MySQL80.

This does not solve the problem. In addition `SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size;` still gives 8388608.

However `mysqld --help --verbose` gives `innodb-buffer-pool-size  67108864`

So it seems that the configuration file did take effect but an individual client process still sees the old value although that sounds impossible.

What do I do to actually increase the buffer pool size for my program?

Comment: Have you tried to disconnect the client and re-connect?

Comment: You are not supposed to create my.cnf manually. MySQL server will create its own my.cnf (or my.ini on Windows) file. You have to locate the file. Normally on Windows, it is under C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server, but can be configured during installation. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597884/mysql-my-ini-location) to get more understanding.

Comment: @Raptor; thanks. I have rebooted the entire computer which, of course, included reconnecting the lient.

Comment: I might be finally able to notice your problem. You created a `my.cnf`, however in Windows OS, you should use: `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini`. Add or modify the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` in the `[mysqld]` section in the file. Restart the service afterwards. `my.cnf` is for Linux.

Comment: Thanks to @raptor and hermanto for offering assistance. Ultimately the problem turned out to be a silly typo of mine in the text above. I put innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G in C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini and it worked.  Note that the MySQL 8 documentation sec 4.2.2.2 and the output of mysqld --help --verbose both say that the options can be in multiple locations and will be checked in this order: C:\WINDOWS\my.ini C:\WINDOWS\my.cnf C:\my.ini C:\my.cnf C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.cnf