# MySQL configuration file sections

Tags: mysql, database, configuration, config, my.ini

I am trying to understand the different sections inside the my.ini configuration file ([client], [mysqld], [mysql]) and so on, I am looking for a guide describing each of the optional sections for the my.ini file, Also I was wondering what is the difference between **init_connect** and **init-connect** and I mean between the underscore(_) and the hyphen(-), Thank you all and have a nice day.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**[mysql]** applies to the mysql command line client - [[mysql and client options]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html)

**[client]** applies to all connecting clients (including mysql cli) - [[mysql and client options]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html)

**[mysqld]** applies to the mysql server - [[server options]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html)

**[mysqldump]** applies to the utility of the same name - [[mysqldump options]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html)

...etc

The difference between the (-) and the (_) is the context in which it is used.

(-) is used in command line parameters, where (_) is used in options file parameters.

You can see more in the docs:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html

Comment: Where can I find the full list of sections and their descriptions?

Comment: According to the docs the option file names are generally supposed to be the same as the command line options with regards to hyphens/underscores.

Comment: A list of the sections is given in the verbose `-v --help` text of a binary. For example for mySQL v5.5.37 `mysqld -v --help` says `The following groups are read: mysqld server mysqld-5.5` somewhere in the beginning. With MariaDB 10.5.6 the list is `mysqld server mysqld-10.5 mariadb mariadb-10.5 mariadbd mariadbd-10.5 client-server galera`. To grep the relevant output out of the massive text, use `mysqld -v --help | grep 'groups are read'`

Answer (score 1):

- `[mysql]` applies to [MySQL Command-Line Client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html).
- `[mysqldump]` applies to [Database Backup Program](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html).
- `[mysqladmin]` applies to [MySQL Server Administration Program](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html).
- `[mysqld]` applies to [MySQL Server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqld.html).
- `[client]` applies to all except `mysqld`.

*[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html) explains it more.