# Is it possible to store a password in my.ini file?

Tags: mysql, database, passwords, ini, my.ini

I am using MySQL 5.5. It contains (commented) lines in my.ini:

```ini
[client]
#password   = your_password
```

If I uncomment "password" line, it does not see it, and allows me to connect with an empty password.

```ini
[client]
user = root
password    = password
```

This does not work too.

If this is not possible, then what are these lines intended for?

Comment: What do you mean by "allows me to connect with an empty password"? So when you specify the password in the `my.ini` file, it does work as expected? And do you have a mysql user login who doesn't need a password or has an empty password?

Comment: No, it does not work with specified password. The mysql has user `root` with empty password. If I have to change password in database, then for what are ini file?

Comment: Wait, is the question how to change the password of a user login in mysql? Or do you want to know what the `my.ini` file with the `[client]` section is for?

Comment: I want to know what the `my.ini` file with the `[client]` section is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[client]` section in the `my.ini` (or `my.cnf`) file is used to provide settings for client programs like the MySQL client application `mysql`. See the documentation about the [option files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html):

> The `[client]` option group is read by all client programs provided in MySQL distributions (but not by mysqld). To understand how third-party client programs that use the C API can use option files, see the C API documentation at Section 28.7.7.50, “mysql_options()”.
>
> The `[client]` group enables you to specify options that apply to all clients. For example, `[client]` is the appropriate group to use to specify the password for connecting to the server. (But make sure that the option file is accessible only by yourself, so that other people cannot discover your password.)

The client applications have a lot of settings/parameters (see `mysql --help`) and if you want to predefine some values as a convenient so they don't need to be written all the time, you can use the `[client]` section.

Answer (score 1):

For example on Windows, you can set the user `john` and the password `banana` under `[client]` in `my.ini` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453555/mysql-configuration-file-sections/77456323#77456323) explains `[client]` and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597884/where-is-mysqls-my-ini-located-on-windows/77461989#77461989) explains where `my.ini` is located on Windows and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57455487/using-my-ini-to-access-mysql-exe-from-the-commandline-without-p/77463735#77463735) explains how to log in by setting only the password `banana` under `[client]` in `my.ini`:

```ini
# "my.ini"

[client]
user="john"
password="banana"
```

Then, you can log in by setting `my.ini`'s location to `--defaults-file=` or `--defaults-extra-file=` as shown below:

```
mysql --defaults-file='C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini'
```

Or:

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file='C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini'
```

*Not setting `my.ini`'s location to `--defaults-file=` or `--defaults-extra-file=` gets error as shown below:

```
mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to connect with `client` section in `my.ini`, but username and password are stored in database, and not in my.ini, so I did it incorrectly. So I (still) don't know why `client` section in `my.ini` is necessary, if you have to specify a password in database and enter it manually in client software (of course, not "_all client programs provided in **MySQL distributions**_", but a third-party client App). So, sorry that my question (and answer) was incorrect. It should be rephrased (or deleted).