# Using my.ini to access mysql.exe from the commandline without -p?

Tags: mysql, database, windows, mysqlcommand, mysql-command-line-client

On Linux, `my.cnf` can be altered such that `mysql -u myusername` will work on the client side without the -p option.  It's safer to use config files to set this up rather than putting the password in at the login line, and it's more convenient (though perhaps less safe) than putting the password in at the default `-p` prompt. But I have yet been able to find a guide on altering the `my.ini` file to achieve this result.  For reference, I have been using: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html (my version is 5.7). I also have read the my.ini file. The language used is too ambiguous and technical for me to understand so I hope to find or eventually compose a real guide.

According to my research:

- `my.cnf` also works.
- mysql will search for .cnf files at the locations specified in the `mysqldvlhelp.txt` file (which does not exist on Windows).

Comment: There is no difference between a my.ini and my.cnf... Mysql does have some os specific parameters, this is unlikely to be one of them. So, I would ry the solution you found for linux.

Answer (score 0):

In your my.ini, you can create a client section to put the user and password.

```
[client]
user=yourmysqluserhere
password=yourpasswordhere
```

Answer (score 0):

For example on Windows, you can set only the password `banana` under `[client]` in `my.ini` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453555/mysql-configuration-file-sections/77456323#77456323) explains `[client]` and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597884/where-is-mysqls-my-ini-located-on-windows/77461989#77461989) explains where `my.ini` is located on Windows and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57448967/is-it-possible-to-store-a-password-in-my-ini-file/77466171#77466171) explains how to log in by setting both the user `john` and the password `banana` under `[client]` in `my.ini`:

```ini
# "my.ini"

[client]
password="banana"
```

Then, you can log in by setting `my.ini`'s location and `john` to `--defaults-file=` or `--defaults-extra-file=` and `-u` respectively as shown below. *`--defaults-file=` or `--defaults-extra-file=` must be the 1st option otherwise there is [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836214/problem-with-mysqldump-defaults-extra-file-option-is-not-working-as-expecte/77463030#77463030):

```
mysql --defaults-file='C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini' -u john
```

Or:

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file='C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini' -u john
```

*Not setting `my.ini`'s location to `--defaults-file=` or `--defaults-extra-file=` gets error as shown below:

```
mysql -u john
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'john'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```