# How to pass password from file to mysql command?

Tags: mysql, shell, unix

I have a shell script which calls the mysql command with one parameter from external file, it looks like this (also I saw this example in other resources):

```
mysql --user=root --password=`cat /root/.mysql`
```

Bit it not working:

> Failed to connect to MySQL server: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

I tried different quotes without success. How to pass it?

UPDATE 1:
Found that I can pass password without space symbol. The problem in this, my root pass contains spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally this line working:

```
 mysql --user=root --password="$(cat /root/.mysql)"
```

or:

```
mysql --user=root --password="$(< /root/.mysql)"
```

Root password must be without quotes: `bla bla bla`

If your password not contains spaces you can use:

```
mysql --user=root --password=`cat /root/.mysql`
```

Comment: this doesn't prevent the password from being exposed in the process cmd line arguments... -_-

Comment: This does not work anymore. This answer provided above by @ThorSummoner is correct - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48939118/116524

Answer (score 27):

Store your password in a protected mysql cnf file:

```
install -m 700 -d /srv/secrets/
install -m 600 /dev/null /srv/secrets/root@localhost.cnf
editor /srv/secrets/root@localhost.cnf
```

Store the password in the client.password ini property

```
[client]
password="password"
```

Include this file as the [first argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3836471/1695680) in your mysql command:

```
mysql \
    --defaults-extra-file=/srv/secrets/root@localhost.cnf \
    --user=root \
    --host=localhost \
    --no-auto-rehash
```

Comment: This works. One can also pass host and username in the same file bypassing the need to pass them separately in the command.

Answer (score 14):

Use `mysql_config_editor` which is installed with the mysql client

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=dev --user=dbuser --host=localhost -p
```

Enter the password and then you can log in like this

```
mysql --login-path=dev
```

Comment: Any idea why I can't pipe the password into this command? `printenv PASS | mysql_config_editor set -p` — it kind of works but it still prompts for the password and I have to press enter.

Answer (score 9):

You should use the `mysql_config_editor` for this.

```
$ mysql_config_editor set \
    --login-path=name_of_connection \
    --host=server.example.com \
    --user=login_as_user \
    --password
```

this will prompt for a password, and save to a .mylogin.cnf file in your homedir.

`mysql --login-path=name_of_connection dbname` will connect to `dbname` on `server.example.com` as `login_as_user`

If `--login-path` is used with other options, ex. `--silent`, `--login-path` **has to be the first argument/option**

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure if that is possible, but you could definitely use configuration 
[file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html).

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
if [ $MYSQL_PASS ]
then
  mysql -u "$MYSQL_ROOT" -p "$MYSQL_PASS" -e "SHOW DATABASES"
else
  mysql -u "$MYSQL_ROOT" -e "SHOW DATABASES"
fi
```