# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, access-denied

I'm trying to log in to mysql via a bash script or to be more specific, I want to check if the passed parameters for the mysql user are thes of an admin user.
For this reason it has to be possible to log in to mysql via a one line command e.g.

`mysql -u $dbadmin -p$dbadminpass`

To test why I didn't work, I tried it myself on the command line an I'm getting this Error:

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I created the use on @localost and gave all privileges. All my reasarch had no reasults so far.
I checked for any typos

Comment: Did you tried what is mentioned in this link ? https://superuser.com/questions/603026/mysql-how-to-fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Comment: I dont supose you have 2 MySQL servers running on different ports do you?

Comment: You can try storing the password in a file, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48939118/11273918

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

or try to connect to 127.0.0.1 not to localhost

Comment: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%';`
gives 
`ERROR 1133 (28000): Can't find any matching row in the user table`

and also after Flushing all privileges it still wont work.

Comment: @basha04 true

Comment: I already created the user with the right password. I even can log in  to MySQL with the admin user and it's password.

Comment: try: -p$dbadminpass => -p $dbadminpass 

Comment: I think there is a missing space

Comment: I can use it if I enter the password via the prompt e.g. `mysql -u admin -p`
`Enter password: mypass` and then I am logged in. It's just the one liner that makes problems.

Comment: @Sanduciorbapesistem the password has to be exactly behind the -p, what I also tried is --password=&dbadminpass but still the error

Comment: try to create another user. ho has access %

Comment: I can create the other user, but still the same error :(

Comment: So I think I know why the error occurs, but it comes with a new struggle.. 
The Password I'm passing got `$$` in it, so if the PW was `Test$$123` it makes `Test4365123` out of it, and I don't know how to disable or workaround the "interpretation" of `$$` or similar e.g. `$1`.. any ideas?
edit: I tried escaping the $-signs within the script an I had no more issuse related to the Question.

Comment: @o'gamingSCV make sense  I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with MySQL installation or set-up.

Each account name consists of both a user and host name like 'user_name'@'host_name', even when the host name is not specified. From the MySQL Reference Manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_usage

MySQL account names consist of a user name and a host name. This enables creation of accounts for users with the same name who can connect from different hosts.

This also allows MySQL to grant different levels of permissions depending on which host they use to connect.

When updating grants for an account where MySQL doesn't recognize the host portion, it will return an error code 1133 unless if it has a password to identify this account.

Also, MySQL will allow an account name to be specified only by it's user name, but in this case it is treated as 'user_name'@'%'.