# mysqldump mysql 8, on a windows server without a password in the command line

Tags: mysql, windows

I want to use a daily batch job without including the password in the batch file.

There are plenty of Linux examples out there. I failed to find a Windows version.

My development machine is using MySQL 8.0.0.12 on Windows Server 2016.
I used the Windows mysql installer and added Mysql server and Workbench.

Location of mysqldump:
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqldump.exe"

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html
Table 4.1 specifies 8 possible locations.  The last options in the table take precedence.

C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data

You can include the sql username and password in a configuration file.
Now you refer to this file when you use mysqldump.
In Linux the configuration files end with .cnf and in windows they are .ini

If not already present, add the mysql bin directory to the Windows path: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin

I changed "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\my.ini".

As a first step I used the root user and password.
all-databases - this will make mysqldump backup all the files.
I added this section to the bottom of the .ini file.

```
[mysqldump]
user=root
password=**yourpasswordhere**
all-databases
```

I thought mysqldump would pick up the user and password from the my.ini and the backup would work.

C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0>"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqlpump.exe"

mysqlpump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) while connecting to the MySQL server
mysqlpump: [ERROR] (11)

Dump process encountered error and will not continue.

Answer (score 1):

However, I found the solution was to use

-defaults-file ="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini"

[SO 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3836471/1692270/)

--this works from the command prompt:

```
 mysqldump  --defaults-file="C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\my.ini"  --result-file test003.sql
```

--result-file this avoids any utf & powershell [issues](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html/) with >