# warnings during table creation process

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I show a MySQL warning that just happened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215692/how-do-i-show-a-mysql-warning-that-just-happened)

I wrote a few lines of code in order to automate the process of table creation.

I run the file through the command: `source filename.sql`

Everything goes smoothly. I mean I get a new database and 6 six tables as I need.

I'm a bit concerned about the fact that I also get a few warnings.
I use the `show warnings` command and I simply get : `Empty set`

The following is the output I get after running: `source filename.sql`

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Database changed
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Is there a way to know what the warnings refer to?

Comment: you say possible duplicate..do you mean that I wrote the same line more than once? I also checked the post you suggested but to no avail..

Comment: @maruo: It means your question itself may be a copy of the linked question. True duplicates dilute the quality of SO and are often closed for that reason. Even if the community decides your post isn't a duplicate, you and other readers of this question can get more info on the topic by reading the linked question.

Comment: AS outlined in the duplicate question, if you use SHOW WARNINGS right after the query that results in warnings, you should be fine. So you'd have to modify your source file to have SHOW WARNINGS after each query that is being affected. The duplicate question indicates that there just isn't anything else you can do...while that might not be the answer you're looking for, it is the "right" answer.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to note is that statements like `drop table if exists NO_SUCH_TABLE` will create warnings, so that's a likely cause in a script like this. Inspect (or post) your script to see if this is the case.

`show warnings` will show you the warnings on the most recent command, ***and only the most recent command***, so you'd have to add `show warnings` after every command in your script if you want to use it to see all warnings.

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head ..my script has statements like : DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Dbis_RG.Categorie; and also CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  Dbis_RG.Categorie Do you think that I can get rid of warnings if I remove those lines? thanks