# Somewhere to write and check SQL

Tags: mysql

Is there somewhere you can input SQL to check syntax etc. because using it in Java just yields a really unhelpful error when trying to run the code: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near..."?

Comment: That's the standard MySQL error, nothing to do with Java.

Comment: so check it inside sql and see what is wrong with it.

Comment: Just run the statement in your favorite SQL client before you put it into the Java code.

Comment: Is that the full error message? IMO, MySQL error messages are actually pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Seems like what you are after.

You can setup table structure in the left part of the window (`CREATE`s and `INSERT`s).

And try your desired `SELECTS` on the right

UPDATE: Though I might add to this that the error you are receiving is in fact an MySQL error you will encounter there as well, but fiddling around can be more handy in a separate tool.

Comment: But the error message won't be more explicit in case of syntax error.

Comment: @X.L.Ant yea you're right i just updated that into my answer as well

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [Show Warning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-warnings.html) and [Show Error](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-errors.html)

You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215692/how-do-i-show-a-mysql-warning-that-just-happened) as well

Answer (score 0):

You can check it in your phpmyadmin where you can just write and run the queries and see if it returns errors and/ or results.

You can also check your syntax at http://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/

You can test your queries and also test if they return desired results at "http://www.martystepp.com/query/?username=cse154&password=cse154" this site provides test databases that are already built so you not only get the syntax right but it provides against logic errors.