# error message of the drop table message

Tags: mysql

I use

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`mytable`;
```

to delete an existing table, the table is deleted, but got the following feedback

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Why I am getting a warning messages?

Answer (score 2):

In `mysql` statement like `Drop Table if exists NO_SUCH_TABLE` will create warnings, so that's a likely cause in a script like this.

So don't worry about this.

Refer below links to know detailed:

[How do I show a MySQL warning that just happened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215692/how-do-i-show-a-mysql-warning-that-just-happened)